# How to get value of High of last bar where plotshape was true?

Tags: pine-script

Im trying to return the High of the last bar in which conditions were met for a signal.
For example whenever "buyretracebar" has plotted to chart, i want to get the value of the high for that bar. thanks!

```
buyretracebar=sl and iff(cloud1, buycloud1filteron, buycloud1filteroff) 
plotshape(buyretracebar, title = "Long Bar")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using a `var` variable and if check.

```
var float highAtRetrace = na

if buyretracebar
    highAtRetrace  := high
```

Or you can use `ta.valuewhen()`

```
ta.valuewhen(buyretracebar, high, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! valuewhen did the trick! the problem i have now is Im trying to get the value of the low of a bar with my conditions as a float variable so that i can use it as a stop loss. This is what i have so far "buylow = ta.valuewhen(buyretracebar, low, 0)" however when i try to use "buylow" as a stop it saying it's returning a boolean not a float any ideas?